# how can i make my curl wait for few seconds before scraping?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

So I am trying to scrape some data from a site.
There are list of names that has to be scraped.
What happens is that, if there are 15 names that needs to be scraped. Out of that only 5 names are scraped.

When I checked the original site, they too load the data in similar way. On loading the site for first time. Only five names are displayed. On reloading 10 names are displayed and trying again shows all 15 data.

Can anybody tell me how to make my cURL wait for few seconds before scraping the original data. so that all of the content can be scraped?

Here is the part snippet of the code with curl set options:

```
    $post = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2 );
    $img_contents = curl_exec($post);
    curl_close($post);

    $html= str_get_html($img_contents);
foreach($html->find('div[id=xxxx]') as $stay2)
{

$stay4=$stay2->find('span[class=xxx]');

    foreach($stay4 as $stay6)
    {   
        echo $abc[]= strip_tags($stay6) ."<br/>";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add in a sleep($seconds) See [PHP sleep function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: Thanks for the ans sem, but its not working :( I guess there has to be some function for curl.

Comment: Ah what you are trying to do is let curl wait in the middle of an exec.
As far as i know that is not possible, what you can do is keep a list with the names, and scrape several times and add it to the list.

If you say they also wait a few seconds it means they do an async fetch (probably a delayed ajax call) what you could do is try and figure out those calls (firebug is a way, i'm sure there are others)
and call those seperatly with curl